# python - create a socket that shows a custom service name in nmap

Tags: python, nmap

I have a piece of python code to listen on a port. The end result I want is that when anyone runs nmap against that IP, a custom name shows up in the service name column. To illustrate my requirement, see below screenshot that shows port 666 as the name doom.

[image]

I tried searching for solutions without any success.

Below is the python code that I'm using to listen on a port:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name, meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
     #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

s.close()
```

If someone could point me in the right direction or help me with the modification I should make to this code, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `nmap` 'detects' services mostly via the fixed `nmap-services` registry. The whole procedure is described @ [Chapter 7. Service and Application Version Detection - Technique Described](https://nmap.org/book/vscan-technique.html) and you won't be able to do this solely through Python (well, you could modify local probes, I guess, but it won't affect remote systems)

Comment: I've looked at the documentation and also looked at nmap-service-probes here[link] (https://nmap.org/book/vscan-fileformat.html) but that doesn't really help me. If not python, is there any other way to set-up a listener to achieve the desired effect in nmap?